# How to dump the extracted tweets line by line into JSON

Tags: python, text-mining, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to extract tweets from Twitter API and dumping them into a JSON format.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="kmart",count=200,lang="en",tweet_mode='extended').items(1000):
    print(tweet.full_text)
    with open('tweets.json', 'a') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(tweet._json))
```

This works just fine but in the tweets.json file there is only one row consisting of all the tweets. 
How do I get every tweet in a separate line ?

Also, in some of the tweets, I still dont get the entire tweet. why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a value for `indent` as an argument to the `json.dumps` method

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="kmart",count=200,lang="en",tweet_mode='extended').items(1000):
print(tweet.full_text)
with open('tweets.json', 'a') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(tweet._json, indent=4))
```

Comment: this creates a new line for every parameter. I want to create a new line for every tweet. So that means, I line for all the parameters belonging to one tweet; next line for next tweet.